# calling multiple forms using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 different forms on 3 different pages. Here is the JS I want to trigger on page load:

```
function init(){
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("delAddr");
    var regForm = document.getElementById("registrationForm");
    var purchaseForm = document.getElementById("purchaseForm");
    checkBox.onchange = sameAddress;    
    regForm.onsubmit = validate;
    purchaseForm.onsubmit = monthCheck;
}
```

But when I am submitting the "purchaseForm", the function "monthCheck" is NOT being called. However, when I click submit on "regForm", the function "validate" is being called.

Comment: Add/show all your related methods in order to get clear idea

Answer (score 0):

While you submit the registration form it'll call `validate()`, if all validations succeed means this form will be submitted to server. So it won't execute next statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. check the code whether you have called the validate function in form tag.
   Like this
2. change the order of statement

   Like this  `purchaseForm.onsubmit = monthCheck;
   regForm.onsubmit = validate;`